# Is there a site that does nothing but spit out whatever POST form parameters were sent to it?

Tags: http, testing, forms, post

Is there a site online available to the general public that does nothing but display whatever form variables (name-value pairs) were sent to it via POST?

Yes, it's very simple and I have already made one myself, the question is to see if there is something generally available in case my box is down or I am working with someone else and I just want to send them a link that does this for debugging purposes.

Comment: If you need something like that, why not roll it yourself?

Comment: What's the point of such a website ? What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: ...considering it's very simple.

Comment: just wondering what kind of general-purpose utilities are out there in case I my own development box is down for some reason or another.

Comment: PostBin is very handy for testing out webhooks. Also check out hurl.it to send post requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: [PostBin](http://www.postbin.org/).

I use it, it's great.

Answer (score 2):

*(this was posted before the edit to the question that nullifies it)*

Post this PHP script in your hosting account (if you have one):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
var_dump($_POST);
```